# Perl function for negative integers using the 2's complement

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to convert AD `maxpwdAge` (a 64-bit integer) into a number of days.

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974598.aspx):

> Uses the IADs interface's `Get` method to retrieve the value of the domain's `maxPwdAge` attribute (line 5).
>
> Notice we use the `Set` keyword in VBScript to initialize the variable named `objMaxPwdAge`—the variable used to store the value returned by `Get`. Why is that?
>
> When you fetch a 64-bit large integer, ADSI does not return one giant scalar value. Instead, ADSI automatically returns an `IADsLargeInteger` object. You use the `IADsLargeInteger` interface's `HighPart` and `LowPart` properties to calculate the large integer's value. As you may have guessed, `HighPart` gets the high order 32 bits, and `LowPart` gets the low order 32 bits. You use the following formula to convert `HighPart` and `LowPart` to the large integer's value.

The existing code in VBScript from the same page:

> ```
> Const ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND = .000000100   ' .000000100 is equal to 10^-7
> Const SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400
>
> Set objDomain = GetObject("LDAP://DC=fabrikam,DC=com")     ' LINE 4
> Set objMaxPwdAge = objDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")              ' LINE 5
>
> If objMaxPwdAge.LowPart = 0 Then
>   WScript.Echo "The Maximum Password Age is set to 0 in the " & _
>                "domain. Therefore, the password does not expire."
>   WScript.Quit
> Else
>   dblMaxPwdNano = Abs(objMaxPwdAge.HighPart * 2^32 + objMaxPwdAge.LowPart)
>   dblMaxPwdSecs = dblMaxPwdNano * ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND   ' LINE 13
>   dblMaxPwdDays = Int(dblMaxPwdSecs / SECONDS_IN_DAY)      ' LINE 14
>   WScript.Echo "Maximum password age: " & dblMaxPwdDays & " days"
> End If
> ```

How can I do this in Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian) may come into this, but you may be able to say

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $num = -37_108_517_437_440;

my $binary = sprintf "%064b", $num;

my ($high, $low) = $binary =~ /(.{32})(.{32})/;

$high = oct "0b$high";
$low  = oct "0b$low";

my $together = unpack "q", pack "LL", $low, $high;

print "num $num, low $low, high $high, together $together\n";
```

Comment: ya .. it will but how to generate the highpart and low part  ( for ex : value is -37108517437440 )

Comment: I thought you had the high and the low 32-bit parts and wanted to build the original 64-bit value.  What do you have?

Comment: i have 64 bit singed integer value :  -37108517437440

Comment: What do you want? The high and low parts?

Comment: The `q` template was valid in Perl 5.8.8: http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/pack.html It may be that you are using a 32-bit version of Perl that can't hold a 64-bit integer.  Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? As far as I can tell from your question, your problem has nothing at all to do with 2’s complement. As far as I can tell, all you need/want to do is

```
use Math::BigInt;

use constant MAXPWDAGE_UNIT_PER_SEC => (
      1000 # milliseconds
    * 1000 # microseconds
    * 10   # 100 nanoseconds
);

use constant SECS_PER_DAY => (
      24 # hours
    * 60 # minutes
    * 60 # seconds
);

my $maxpwdage_full = ( Math::BigInt->new( $maxpwdage_highpart ) << 32 ) + $maxpwdage_lowpart;

my $days = $maxpwdage_full / MAXPWDAGE_UNIT_PER_SEC / SECS_PER_DAY;
```

Note that I deliberately use 2 separate constants, and I divide by them in sequence, because that keeps the divisors smaller than the range of a 32-bit integer. If you want to write this another way and you want it to work correctly on 32-bit perls, you’ll have to keep all the precision issues in mind.